# Magento Adding a Custom Layout to individual product

Tags: magento

Hi

I have an online estore setup using magento 1.6.2 CE, an have a very novice like question!!

THE SITUATION / FACTS:

1. I have created Categories and sub categories.

2. To categories i have added a custom template for left navigation.

3. I want this template to also apply to products that i have applied to the category/ sub category. For this, i have selected Apply To Products under Custom Design to Yes.

4. i want custom left navigations for products in different categories./p>

HOw ITS ACTING:

when i access the product using the category name/ sub category name, the template is applied to it on the individual products page. For example, say the category is MENS, and the product name is shirts, so when i access it using www.mydomain.com/MENS/shirts.html the template is applied and i see the custom left menu.

PROBLEM:

when the shirts page is accessed directly, like magento does, ie www.mydomain.com/shirts.html, the custom template is not applied. it shows blank.

what is the possible workaround for this? I have tried setting APPLY TO PRODUCTS to NO, and then adding custom layout template to each product individually... but this is too cumbersome..

Thanks

Moody

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just set 'Use Categories Path for Product URLs' to yes in Configuration > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization?

Comment: no this does not help... ive set Use Category path for product url's but magento, it appears magento has  an inbuilt system that somehow always shows products specially if searched, without category names etc. This also applies specially in canonical urls and in magento generated sitemaps.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your catalog.xml file in

app>design>frontend>base>default>layout>catalog.xml

You may already have this file located in your theme folder, if not copy it across.

Search for

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="root">
```

the line below this should state something like the following:

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

Edit this so that it states this instead

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
```

Notice the column denotation has changed from right to left, re-upload the file. Hey presto it is done!

[emagen - Magento Designers, Shepherds Bush, West London](http://www.emagen.co.uk)